# converting dd/mm field to dd--mm--yy with system year in Hive

Tags: date, datetime, hive

I have a date field and time field in a table.
1) convert mm/dd to mm/dd/yyyy- I want to add current system year to the date.
2) concat date and time fields to form date_time field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample query:

```
select concat(concat(concat(concat(date, '/'), year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))), ' '), time) from <table_name>;
```

Comment: Thank you Durga V.G. Query ran and got as reqd. My sample  input 11/27|12:03:50.9283
11/27|11:11:33:4738
select concat(concat(concat(concat(date, '/'), year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))), ' '), time) from dt_time; Output is 11/27/2015 12:03:50.9283
11/27/2015 11:11:33:4738

Comment: i also tried (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(nids_date ,'MM/dd'), 'dd-MM-'), YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())), '  ', nids_time),  'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))

Comment: insert into table nids select 
     cast (concat(concat(concat(concat(nids_date, '/'), 
     year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))), ' '),
     nids_time))
    as timestamp, 
     id1, iface, eve_m, priority, 
    Prot, sIP, sport, dIP, 
    dport from nid_tem; What is wrong in the query? its giving me error for brackets.